# !important tag - the logic of it

Tags: css

Please help me with this...

Given this css:

```
/* General css */

.my_element {
height:50px !important;
}

/* Webkit-only css */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.my_element {
height:100px !important;
}
}

/* Ipad specific css */

@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
.my_element {
height:200px !important;
}
}
```

Notice that `height` has the `!important` attribute in all cases.

Question: Will `my_element` have a height of 100px when viewed in webkit browsers? Will it be 200px when viewed on an Ipad? Or will it be 50 px on all devices and browsers?

Comment: 100px on webkit browser and I'm guessing 200px on ipad.

Comment: The CSS will cascade as normal, so if the `@media` query is active the corresponding height will be active accordingly. Avoid `!important` as much as possible. It is not needed in the vast majority of situations.

Comment: It will [work the same as this example.](http://jsbin.com/qoyoh/1/edit) (open the CSS tab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As all three styles have `!important` it won't make any difference between them. That will only affect their precedence compared to other styles that doesn't have `!important`.

For rules with the same specificity (same number of id, class and element selectors), the rules that come last will take precedence. That means that the webkit and iPad specific rules will take precedence when they are used.

Answer (score 1):

If there is multiple styles with !important, the last one applied will be the one active on the element. And styles from single sheet apply in the order they are written.

So in your case, the height will have the last value applied. So 50px or 100px or 200px (depending which media query is active for aprticular browser).

Answer (score -2):

I would say that the height will vary depending on whether you're on an iPad or in a webkit browser.

Edited for clarity: what I meant is that it won't be 50px on all devices but 200px on iPad and 100px in webkit browsers.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. _height will vary_ could still be 50px / 100px or 200px/